# ANTLR, missmatched token exception, expected \u000F

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlr3

when I run input

```
integer function () :
2+2+2;
integer x;
3-1-2;
end.
```

on my grammar:

```
evaluator
   :    type 'function' '(' ')' ':'
        (expression ';' | declaration ';')*
        'end' '.'
        EOF
   ;


declaration
    :   type IDENT (':=' expression)? ';'
    ;

type
    :   'integer'
    |   'double'
    |   'boolean'
    |   'void'
    ;

term
    :   IDENT
    |   '(' expression ')'
    |   INTEGER
    ;

unary
    :   ('+' | '-')* term
    ;

mult
    :   unary (('*' | '/' | 'mod') unary)*
    ;

expression
    :   mult (('+' | '-') mult)*
    ;
```

I get missmatched token exception on character `3` from the input, expected `\u000F`. When i erase line `integer x;` from the input, everything works fine. Any idea what `\u000F` means and why it is expected?

I tried rewriting every rule, nothing helps.

IDENT can be only letters, INTEGER only digits. expression is integers and '+' or '-' between them.

Thanks.

Comment: Does ANTLR produce any output when you generate the lexer and parser from your grammar?

Comment: yes, everything matches as it should, up to character '3' from the input

Comment: I'm referring to the process of converting the `.g` file to one or more `.java` files, before you compile them.

Comment: ye, sure, lexer and parser are correctly generated without errors

Comment: @Milos add your expression rule and your lexer grammar wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to check.

I think I see the problem. Your `declaration` rule eats the `;` but your main rule `(expression ';' | declaration ';')*` also expects to get the semi colon.  Remove the `;` from your declaration rule.

ie rewrite your declaration rule to be:

```
declaration
    :   type IDENT (':=' expression)?  <- don't parse the semi colon here
    ;
```

One check the source of the file.  Unicode character `\u000F` is SHIFT IN which isn't that common but can be used in irc environments to remove formatting. [See this link](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1953)

I often use a hex editor for verifying the file format is actually what I think it is.  A text file  can never lie to a hex editor:)

If you want to verify in aonther file you can usually create it by typeing `ALT 15` at some other point in your file to see if `ANTLR` gives you the same error where you put the control character.

If its not the file encoding then I'd really go over your expression rule and lexer grammar to make sure there is nothing wrong with them.  Because you didn't post them we can't help verify.

Comment: when I open the grammar in hex editor, what am I looking for? I edited the post, expression rules are included

Comment: @Milos, you'd be looking for the Unicode character `\u00F`.  Basically you'd be looking for anything that isn't a `3` or `+` on your third and fourth lines.

Comment: so you think, that the character is in input, not in the rule? here's the rule in hex editor http://i.imgur.com/J4DNLXZ.png

Comment: @Milos, yes I think the token is in the source file not the grammar

Comment: well, I'm hardcoding the input into interpreter, there is no source file.. o wait, i know what you mean

Comment: no wait, when I erase the line "integer x;" from the input, everything works fine, when I put it back, there is this error again, so it can't be in input

Comment: @Milos ok, your unary rule probably should use a `?` instead of a `*`, unless you want to allow `+++x`

Comment: yes, I wanted to allow that, but I'm goind to change it to "?", but nothing is gonna resolve with that change..

Comment: @Milos check my update.  Your declaration shouldn't parse the semi colon as your top level rule also expects to parse the semi colon.

Comment: wow, you rock! thanks many times, I thought, it was set to greedy=false, but it wasn't..